# Group a dataframe and select one cell among them based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset look like this

`Tr,    Date,    Time
AV81312,20161014,121000
AV81312,20161014,160221
AV85012,20170422,150858
AV85012,20161108,11137
AV86157,20170426,45747
AV86157,20170426,45744
AV86157,20160813,134312`

I need to select only one item from each `Tr` having latest record i.e latest record having date and and time higher

Required output is

`Tr,    Date,    Time
AV81312,20161014,160221
AV85012,20170422,150858
AV86157,20170426,45747`

My code is

`df2 = read_csv("sample.csv")
df2 = df2.values
x = []
for i in df2:
  for j in df2:
    if i[2] == j[2]:
      if i[3] >= j[3]:
        x.append(i)`
It wasn't working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Time'].astype(str)),format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
df.loc[df.groupby('Tr')['Date_Time'].idxmax()].drop('Date_Time', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
        Tr      Date    Time
0  AV81312  20161014  160221
1  AV85012  20170422  150858
2  AV86157  20170426   45747
```

Comment: Didn't flash the idea to merge date and time. Very much thanks @vivek